# ProSavage8 KM266/KL266 refuses to work in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, drivers, opengl, mesa

I am trying to configure an old laptop, and this is driving me up the wall. I have spent at least ten hours trying solutions to no avail.

I initally installed mesa 7.11, which did not work. I currently have mesa 8 along with the Xorg Edgers mesa-legacy 7.11 drivers.

`sudo lshw -c video` returns:

```
display UNCLAIMED     
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: VT8375 [ProSavage8 KM266/KL266]
       vendor: S3 Inc.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 66MHz
       capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=64 maxlatency=255 mingnt=4
```

My current xorg.conf looks like this:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "X.org Configured"
    Screen         "Default Screen"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
EndSection

Section "Files"
    ModulePath   "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/misc"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/:unscaled"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/:unscaled"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi"
    FontPath     "/var/lib/defoma/x-ttcidfont-conf.d/dirs/TrueType"
    FontPath     "built-ins"
EndSection

Section "Module"
    Load  "record"
    Load  "dbe"
    Load  "extmod"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier  "Keyboard0"
    Driver      "kbd"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier  "Mouse0"
    Driver      "mouse"
    Option      "Protocol" "auto"
    Option      "Device" "/dev/input/mice"
    Option      "ZAxisMapping" "4 5 6 7"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "Monitor Generic"
    VendorName   "Monitor Vendor"
    ModelName    "Monitor Model"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier  "Card0"
    Driver      "savage"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Default Screen"
    Device     "Card0"
    Monitor    "Monitor Generic"
    SubSection "Display"
    Depth 32
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

I have tried many different Xorg options, downgrades of driver packages and the like. The only two outcomes I have been able to achieve are:

NoAccel in xorg.conf: VGA driver is used, and GLXgears gets ~5 FPS. Not an optimal outcome.

Anything else: Any OpenGL application crashes on startup with the error "Wait returned -16" and the system completely locks up, necessitating power cycling.

Well, there is a third outcome that I noticed: enabling ShadowFB caused artifacts all over the screen and made the bottom half of the screen unusable.

Any help is much appreciated. I have seen that this issue has been raised before on several websites while trying to diagnose this problem, but nothing suggested has worked.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix it...Kind of. It still says display unclaimed and GLXinfo crashes, but I can run OpenGL applications.

I added this to Xorg.conf

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier  "Card0"
    Driver      "savage"    
    Option      "AGPMode"   "4"
    Option      "HWCursor"  "True"
    Option      "UseBIOS"   "False"
    Option      "ShadowStatus"  "False"
    Option      "AGPSize" "16"
    Option      "DmaMode" "Any"
    Option      "DmaType" "AGP" 
    Option      "BusType" "AGP" 
    Option      "ForceInit" "Yes" 
    VideoRam    32768 
EndSection

Section "dri"
    Mode         0666
EndSection
```

I also messed around with settings in DRIconf. I still don't understand what the problem was as the savage driver was being loaded correctly, DRI rendering was active, and I could find no errors in any logs.

Comment: I'm currently having this exact same problem and trying out your solution.